# All my JetBrains can't launch with IDEA.exe (no response when clicking), but it could launch through idea.pat

Tags: intellij-idea, clion

I click IDEA.64 and there is no response. However, when I click idea.pat, it could launch. I am very confused. I tried to uninstall and install again, but it doesn't work. Also, my Clion has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from JB's community by Konstantin Annikov :
'Please install https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe. The root cause is that vcruntime140.dll from Visual C++ Redistributable package failed to load. It is one of jbr\bin\awt.dll dependencies. Visual Studio makes changes to C++ tools sometimes and we are working on including this dll into IDE installation, or exclude its functionality.C++ tools are needed to run IntelliJ IDEA'